# Maven DBUnit PreparedStatement.setNull(int, int, String) method is not implemented

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, maven, dbunit

I'm having a problem using maven executing some test with dbunit.

The error appear when I execute the next line:

`DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(connection, dataset);`

The error is:

`org.dbunit.DatabaseUnitException: Exception processing table name='TABLENAME'
    at es.dao.TestDAO.cleanDB(TestDAO.java:63)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The PreparedStatement.setNull(int, int, String) method is not implemented.`

The error doesn't appear if execute the test class directly from eclipse.

I have look for the PreparedStatement class in the dependencies and it's not. So it must use the one from jdk java.sql.PreparedStatement which includes that method.

I'm using the dependecy

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
   <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.4</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Any idea about why I'm having the error only with maven?

Thanks